# write on file from serial in python in windows

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, writefile

I trying to have a very simple script to read data from serial port and write it on a txt file. My data are always the same and for example look like this : '4\r\n'

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout=0) 

while 1:
   data=ser.readline()
   print data
   f = open('myfile.txt','w') 
   data=str(data)
   f.write(data)
   f.close()
   time.sleep(1)
```

I am using python2.7 on windows 7
my print work fine I get the data, but I couldn't write on file...

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `'w'` option in `open()` tells python to delete your file first, then open it.  Try changing the `'w'` to an `'a'` so that Python appends new data to the end of the file, rather than deleting the file every time.

```
f = open('myfile.txt', 'a')
```

You can read more about the `open` function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).  Specifically, check out the documentation for the `mode` argument.

Comment: It would be simpler to just move the `open` out of the loop and use a `with` statement to ensure the file gets closed.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree.  I wanted to give an answer that changed as little as possible, but a better solution would be something like you described.